How to tell whether a function is a hypergeometric function knowing its first series coefficients?
Suppose one knows the first coefficients $\alpha_i$ of the series expansion of a function $f(t)$ at point $t=0$
\begin{equation}
f(t) \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n} \alpha_i \cdot t^i
\end{equation}
Question: is it possible to tell whether $f(t)$ is likely to be a hypergeometric function (possibly generalized) and if so, provide the different coefficients $(a)_n$, $(b)_n$ and $(c)_n$ ?

To show that $f$ is hypergeometric you can show that it is annihilated by a differential operator of the form
$$ \mathcal{L} \, = \, D \, (D+b_1-1) \cdots (D+b_q-1) - t \, (D+a_1) \cdots (D+a_p) $$
with $D = t \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$. To find a candidate for $\mathcal{L}$, expand $f$ to some sufficiently large order and try to find polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree $p$ and $q$ such that your expansion of $f$ is annihilated by $D \, Q(D)-t \, P(D)$. This is linear algebra and once you have a candidate $\mathcal{L} = D \, Q(D)-t \, P(D)$ you can read off the parameters of the associated hypergeometric function from the factorizations of $P$ and $Q$.
